# Allow future developers block my logger

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am using logback for logging and have no logger set, just root logger:

```
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

In class it looks like this:

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(foo.bar.MyClass.class); // foo.bar is package definition
```

Can future developers block my logging by defining rules for my packages, like this:

```
<logger name="foo.bar" level="OFF" />
```

Or, I must define my logger in class like this:

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("MyCoolLogger");
```

And people can disable it thanks to given name:

```
<logger name="MyCoolLogger" level="OFF" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Logback loggers inherit settigns from their parent loggers, so `foo.bar.MyClass` will inherit settings from `foo.bar`